# How to write hashCode() for subClass

Tags: java, hashcode

I have a question about hashCode. For example:

```
class A{
   String name;
   int age;

   @Override
   public int hashCode(){
       int hash = 0;
       hash = age;
       hash = 31*hash + name.hashCode();
   }
}
class B extends A{
}
class C extends A{
}
```

My question is, if I instantiate one B object and one C object with the same name and age. Then the hashCode() for A and B are the same as well. Is it correct for hashCode()? if not, what should I do to modify my code?

Comment: Do `B` and `C` define any members that are considered significant with regards to `hashCode` or `equals`?

Comment: It depends on `B` and `C` definitions...

Answer (score 2):

Sure, that's ok for `hashCode()` to do that.

Of course, if `B` or `C` adds any new fields (which would be common), then they should override `hashCode()`, call `super.hashCode()` and "extend" the value as well.

Also, as @bradimus hinted in a comment to question, when you override `hashCode()`, you should very likely also override `equals()`.

Comment: It depends on the new fields.  hashCode should return a value consistent with the object's identity.  Not all fields contribute to identity.